# Idiomatic way to assign value if not null

Tags: kotlin

I want to achieve this:

```
val foo = if (getNullableValue() != null) getNullableValue() else computeDefaultValue()
```

What I don't like about it is the repetition of `getNullableValue()`. Trying to get rid of the repetion I came up with this:

```
val foo = getNullableValue()?.also{}?: run { computeDefaultValue() }
```

Not sure if that's considered idiomatic though. And the IDE warns about the empty body of `also`. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the Elvis Operator is for:

```
val foo  = getNullableValue() ?: computeDefaultValue()
```

For example:

```
fun getNullableValue1(): Int? {
    return null
}

fun getNullableValue2(): Int? {
    return 22
}

fun computeDefaultValue(): Int {
    return 44
}

println(getNullableValue1() ?: computeDefaultValue())
println(getNullableValue2() ?: computeDefaultValue())
```

Result:

```
44
22
```